# How to completely disable log4net

Tags: .net, log4net

I have a log4net in one .net web application. But i want to completely disable it. Is there any configuration setting that can be set in the web.config in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

to disable all logging messages you can set Logging level to OFF:

> Setting the Threshold on the Hierarchy to Level OFF will disable all
>   logging from that Hierarchy. This can be done in the log4net
>   configuration file by setting the "threshold" attribute on the log4net
>   configuration element to "OFF". For example:
>
> `<log4net threshold="OFF" />`

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html

Answer (score 9):

Setting the Threshold on the Hierarchy to Level OFF will disable all logging from that Hierarchy. This can be done in the log4net configuration file by setting the `"threshold"` attribute on the log4net configuration element to "OFF". For example:

```
<log4net threshold="OFF" />
```

Refer this: [How do I completely disable all logging at runtime?](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#runtime-disable)