# turn on and of the logger log4net

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

i am using log4net for logging, now i want that logging does not remain ON every time, it only report when we turn it ON, i have little bit idea about it, e.g. `if(logger.IsDebugEnabled)`
here is my method on which i want to apply condition.

```
public static void Log(LoggingLevel loggingLevel, string message, string logSource, object loggingProperties)
    {
        Log(loggingLevel, message, logSource, loggingProperties, null);
    }
```

i am assuming that "if(logger.IsDebugEnabled)" this condition check only debug, and i want it on parent that just act like an ON/OFF for log.
Any one can guide me about it.

Comment: With log4net you can configure what loglevel should be logged during runtime and how (http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html). Usually you use the `if(logger.IsXXXXEnabled)` only when executing time consuming steps just to produce a log message.

Comment: Do you want to turn logging on or off for the entire application at once, or do you want to toggle whether certain calls (Debug/Info/...) are logged at runtime?

Comment: i want to check condition for once when about to call method.

Comment: @Unihedron:  thankyou really helpful, that was the exactly Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate post. Please refer to the below link:

[How to completely disable log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621083/how-to-completely-disable-log4net)

or

[An Introduction to the log.net logging library usi](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8264/An-Introduction-to-the-log-net-logging-library-usi)

You will have to use different thresholds for logging.

Comment: thanks for Answer, this was really helpful "how to completely disable log4net" that was exactly what i need..