# How to completely disable the logger

Tags: c#, log4net

I know about this post to disable the log4net logger: [Stackoverflow: How to completely disable log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621083/how-to-completely-disable-log4net).

But I wonder whether the logger is actually inactive, when I use code like this:

```
log.debug("some debug text");
```

I think about an extra solution to set something like a config switch in the config file (app.config), that signals my program to omit or use the part of source code for output logging, for example:

i.e. in my app.config

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="enableLog" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

then in the source code:
... determine the value from the config and put it in an local variable and...

`if (enableLog) log.debug("some debug text");`

What do you think, do I need such kind of solution for more performance or is it a stupid idea?

Comment: Sounds like micro-optimization, something you don't want to do unless you have a good reason for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to completely disable log4net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621083/how-to-completely-disable-log4net)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what log4net does already. When you call

> log.debug("some debug text");

it internally checks the log4net.xml configuration file for

```
<log4net threshold="OFF" /> //it could also be ALL, DEBUG, INFO etc..
```

and if it is switched off, it won't continue any further with the logging.

In my opinion there's no need for such an optimization since log4net already does it. I wouldn't say that an extra layer of checks will bring up a noticeable improvement on performance. It depends on what your application is about and if 1 millisecond is vital. I could also say that log4net is pretty optimized and I never needed to make such optimizations on my projects.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are thinking of using an app.config setting...i think you'll find log4net provides similar options anyway. You could always check the IsDebugEnabled flag which you control in your log4net config by setting the Log level.

```
if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
     Log.DebugFormat("My text");
```

You could also use a filter to prevent all logging anyway.
Something like

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
```

Hope that's of help.

Comment: I would point out that there isn't much point in using Log.IsDebugEnabled if you are logging straight text. Where it becomes useful is if your log command is calling properties or methods which you are trying to avoid.